# Battery does not resume charging after power interruption, if brand new HP Envy notebook is powered off

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I got this laptop just yesterday, and I have a weird problem.

**Configuration of laptop:**

```
CPU: Intel Core i7 5500U @ 2.4GHz (Turbo 3.0 GHz).
CPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 850M (4GB dedicated).
RAM: 8GB DDR3L.
HDD: 1 TB Toshiba.
OS: Windows 8.1 (Single language/ x64).
Battery: 4 Cell Li-ion standard battery.
Charger power: 90W.
Model: HP Envy K203TX.
```

**Problem Description:**

The notebook won't charge when it's turned OFF.

**To trigger the problem:**

1. Power OFF notebook, and close the lid.
2. Connect the charger, the battery starts charging as indicated by the AMBER LED near the charger port.
3. Power OFF the charger (disconnect it from AC mains), the notebook stops charging, the LED goes OFF.
4. Power the charger back ON (reconnect its AC mains), the notebook won't charge. The LED stays OFF.
5. To resume charging, I have to try either of the following:

   - Turn OFF charger again, leave it OFF for 15 minutes or so, turn it back on, charging resumes.
   - Unplug the charger from the notebook charger port, and plug it back in, charging resumes.
   - Open the lid, charging resumes.

**Other findings:**

1. The problem cannot be triggered when Windows is running/ computer is powered ON.
2. Problem cannot be triggered when the lid is kept open.

**Troubleshooting steps tried so far:**

1. Cycled battery once, problem persists.
2. Power-cycled notebook (removed battery, unplugged charger, pressed and held power button for 30 secs, put battery and charger back in). Problem persists.
3. Updated BIOS from HP website, problem persists.
4. Ran the "Diagnostics" from BIOS, it says "No problems found".
5. Ran "HP battery health check" software in Windows, it says battery health is 100%, cycle count is 1/300, status is OK.

**Why's this happening?**

It doesn't look normal to me. My old laptop, also HP, does not behave this way.

Is this 'by design'?

Do new notebooks behave this way? Or did I get a defective product?

Comment: I'm tempted to say the title should be: *"Battery stops charging when charger is switched off and quickly switched back on again during charging"*. And that's probably just a bug that nobody noticed. (Why switch off the charger to start with...? Why does it even have a switch for that? Sounds like *"Doctor it hurts when I press here...*")

Comment: The charger doesn't have an OFF switch. M switchin it On/Off using the mains/ AC switch on the wall outlet :P What do I do? Shall i return the notebook and get another one? I was in a chat session with HP support, the lady took remote control of the computer and performed some troubleshooting, nothing unusual, she checked power settings and battery health and all.. And then told me she can send me a tech at home to check it out, i denied. Shall I ask for the tech? Or shall I just return it back to HP and ask for a new computer? It's just 1 day old, got it yesterday, and has 3 years warranty..

Comment: Paid $1200 for it. I was expecting perfection. This isn't perfect is it. It's not a dirt-cheap notebook that i can throw away after 6 months. m expecting to use it for at least 4 years. A 'bug' doesn't paint a very good picture about the brand's quality control :-/ It's pretty weird that out of the millions using HP Envy notebooks, I'm the first one to notice it. Odds are, they know it, but they can't / won't  fix it.

Comment: (Just for future reference: same question on http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/strange-behavior-while-charging-on-quot-just-purchased-quot/td-p/5117577)

Comment: It was me. I asked it there. No one else on that forum wrote back reporting they have the same issue. Could it be this isn't an universal problem, and i just got a bad product? I just tried this same On/Off cycle on my other HP notebook (ProBook) again now, the issue is NOT present in this other computer. It charges every time I power ON the charger, dosen't matter if the notebook itself is powered ON or OFF. I asked the same question on Tom's Hardware too, no replies there.. This is the Tom's link: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2690526/strange-battery-problem-brand-laptop.html

Comment: I edited the title; this might be more attractive to other HP Envy owners, and maybe will make them test too.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find any solutions?